# VS 2010 Connection to Cube

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, ssas, olap

I want to have possibility to connect to Olap Cube, but cant figure a way to do it. The problem is that in VS 2010 Microsoft havent implemented Buisness inteligence logic/projects where a part of it is Analysis Services. In VS 2008 analysis services is implemented but silverlight 4 is not compatible with VS2008, and i need Silverlight 4 to complete my funktionality.

i have already tryed :

dataset
OLeDBConnection
ADO.NET model
Linq to SQL connection

So, is there a way to connect to Olap Cube in VS 2010?

Answer (score 0):

using like C#? have you tried ADOMD.net